# How to enable production server request in apiary new Interactive Documentation Renderer?

Tags: apiary

When I try to make production server request in Apiary with new document renderer enabled in the settings, I get the following response always

```
We encountered an error. Please try later.
```

However, turning off the new document renderer, the request works as expected.

Please also tell if it is something related to settings/configuration or if this feature is disabled?

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like CORS limitation. I would advise to either:

- Enable [CORS on your API](https://www.w3.org/TR/cors/#cors-api-specification-advice);
- Or have your own proxy server that allows CORS requests.

Comment: Does not work with debugging proxy also. Can you explain why it works without new document renderer?

Comment: We are exploring the best way how to support CORS in the new documentation renderer. The previous version has some workarounds with know limitations https://help.apiary.io/tools/interactive-documentation/#console-modes